# Website search field not working - Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome

So this was brought to my attention today, that our website search field does not work in chrome... I cannot click and enter text into the text field, nor click the search icon to initiate searching...

Sorry I do not know the specifics as to what is causing this, nor did I develop this. One of our developers who left quite some time ago did. I am now in charge of trying to figure this out.

FireFox and IE 11 seems to working fine.

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

```
      <div class="searchbox" id="searchbox"> 
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
              function RunSearch() { 
                    window.location.href = "http://search.domain.com:8765/query.html?ql=&col=web1&qt=" + document.getElementById("search").value; 
              } 
        </script> 
              <div class="formSrchr"> 
                    <input type="text" size="20" name="qt" id="search" value="Search" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Search') {this.value=''}" onblur="if(this.value == ''){this.value ='Search'}" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="qlOld" id="qlOld" value="" /> 
                    <input type="hidden" name="colOld" id="colOld" value="web1" /> 
                    <input type="image" name="imageField" alt="search" src="/_images/search-mag.gif" onclick="RunSearch();" /> 
              </div> 
  </div> <!-- /searchbox -->
```

Comment: Wow.  That's not good code...  I can't be certain, but Chrome has a habit of making invalid HTML not work.  There is no form tag, which could be your problem.

Comment: credit for the most obscure and strange way to do search feature! `One of our developers who left quite some time ago did.` I hope he changed profession!

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to open the Developer tools in chrome and look at the Javascript debug window.  That should tell you what's going on in the more general case.  In either case, I recommend rewriting that snippet like this:

```
<div class="searchbox" id="searchbox">
  <div class="formSrchr">
    <form action="http://search.domain.com:8765/query.html" method="get">
      <input type="text" size="20" name="qt" value="Search" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Search') {this.value=''}" onblur="if(this.value == ''){this.value ='Search'}" onmouseup="return false" />
      <input type="hidden" name="ql" id="ql" value="" />
      <input type="hidden" name="col" id="col" value="web1" />
      <input type="image" alt="search" src="/_images/search-mag.gif" />
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

The standard form element will behave the way it's supposed to without JavaScript.  All the named inputs will be added as URL parameters just like it did before.  That's what `method="get"` does.  For most forms, the default `method="post` is best; however, for search you aren't really posting anything.  There are some strange proxy servers that disable all HTTP POST calls to prevent people behind that proxy from accidentally sharing information they aren't supposed to.  The `method="get"` allows those people to at least search your site.

NOTE: based on some searching around, Chrome needs you to [disable the `onmouseup` event](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2973172/476048) for focus and blur to work as expected.  My HTML form above has that change in it already for you.

In HTML 5, you can simplify it even more by using the `placeholder` tag.  It would look like this:

```
<input type="text" size="20" name="qt" placeholder="Search" value=""/>
```

That removes all the Javascript from your search form.

Answer (score 0):

This is bad code and i suggest an entire re-write.. As for a quick fix..

You could try the following :

```
var searchTerm = document.getElementById("search").value;
location.assign("http://search.domain.com:8765/query.html?ql=&col=web1&qt=" + searchTerm );
```

Or

```
function RunSearch() { 
                    window.location.href = "http://search.domain.com:8765/query.html?ql=&col=web1&qt=" + document.getElementById("search").value; 
                    return false;    
              }
```

***But dont use this.. re-write it!***